# Checkout option of Ajax Cart Popup does not redirect to one step checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

I am using Ajax Cart Popup
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ajax-cart-popup.html

And One step checkout extensions.
But when I click on check out button in popup cart, it redirects me to default one-page checkout. I want it to redirect me to one step checkout page.

What is needed to be changed?

Comment: You might need to contact the `ajax-cart-popup` module creator as it looks like there is a conflict between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Please change code in file : `HusseyCoding_AjaxCartPopup_Block_Popup`

**Find bellow function**

```
public function getCheckoutUrl()
{
  return $this->_getCheckoutUrl();      
}
```

**And replace below function**

```
 public function getCheckoutUrl()
        {
//Make sure please put your One step checkout extension module enable or disable condition here
            if (!$this->helper('onestepcheckout')->isRewriteCheckoutLinksEnabled()){
                return $this->_getCheckoutUrl();
            }
            return $this->getUrl('onestepcheckout', array('_secure'=>true));
        }
```